# Font size of PySimpleGUI calendar / date picker

Tags: python, calendar, pysimplegui

I'm using the date picker element of PySimpleGUI and I want to increase the font size of the calendar popup window that is opened when you click on the CalendarButton. But I've only found how to change the size of the text on the button itself. How do I increase the font of the calendar popup?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
fnt = 'Arial 12'
layout = [[sg.In(key='-INCAL1-', enable_events=True, visible=False),
           sg.Col([[sg.CalendarButton('Change date', target='-INCAL1-', pad=None, 
                                key='-CAL1-', font=fnt, format=('%Y-%m-%d'))]])]]

window = sg.Window('Calendar', size=(400, 400), resizable=True).Layout(layout).finalize()
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
window.close()
```

[image: Button and calendar popup window]

Comment: Calendar button calls the popup_get_date function. Popups are convenience functions, so the way to customize them is to create your own popup window with the fonts you would like to use.  To duplicate the effect, add a button and then it's clicked, open your own date chooser window and fill in the input field with the results from your function.

Comment: You can copy the code to `popup_get_date()` from your PySimpleGUI.py file as a starting point for making your custom date chooser with bigger fonts.